# How to disable eldoc when using TRAMP (editing files over SSH)

Tags: spacemacs, tramp, hooks, eldoc

Eldoc really bogs down the editor when used over SSH with TRAMP. I want to disable it in those cases.
What I've tried is this:

```
  (defun no-tramp-eldoc ()
    (interactive)
    (when (string-prefix-p "/ssh" (buffer-file-name)) (anaconda-eldoc-mode -1)))
  (add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'no-tramp-eldoc)
```

Regarding that last line, I'm not sure if it should be

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'no-tramp-eldoc)
```

instead, but I've tried both and it does not work.

The `no-tramp-eldoc` function itself should be correct: when called manually, eldoc does get disabled in TRAMP/SSH buffers --- it's the hook that does not work; maybe something re-enables eldoc after the hook has run?

I'm using Spacemacs.